# Recording a video and audio via a devices camera

Tags: html, flash, audio, video, webcam

I'm looking into how I can record video / audio via a devices camera. The recording will be temporarily stored on the server, I'll then upload to Vimeo before deleting the original video from my server. The latter part I can do, the first is proving to be difficult.

I would have loved to have used the getUserMedia API but I haven't found a way to record both the audio and the video in a reliable way. I've looked at MediaStreamRecorder but that isn't currently supported. Other solutions such as:
http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/31486670538/creating-webm-video-from-getusermedia

Are too slow and work in too few browsers for it to be considered for a production site. Which leads me to believe the only way to do this is use Flash (blurgh).

Which leads me to my question. Has anyone had experience implementing something similar? Is there a solution that will perform well on most modern browsers but doesn't require downloading big libraries. I'll be providing a file upload fallback so in terms of browser support it would just need to work in most modern browsers.

I'm mostly looking for guidance and ideas on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Ok, after further investigations a HTML5 solution definitely won't work for my needs. So I'm resorting to an as3 application running on a flash media server ( Red5 )

Answer (score 1):

There is no broadly available solution to this.  You can use Flash or Silverlight or Java on browsers that support them.  You can use getUserMedia on browsers that support them.  But even if you do all of those, some browsers like Safari (and thus iOS) are left out until they implement getUserMedia

Comment: This was my solution initially until I found out that recording video and audio together can't be done natively and any potential solutions are a bit clunky and unreliable. Unless someone can point out that I'm wrong, I would love to be wrong!